# Is there a way to automatically sync Ubuntu One and the Android client? 

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, android, client, automatic

Is there a way to automatically sync Ubuntu One and the Android client?
I have tried 2 phones and all I get in "Account and sync" menu is "sync is off" in both.
Is it normal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One Files uses AccountManager (what you see under Accounts & Sync) to store the OAuth token (which allows access to Ubuntu One) and other small amount of metadata related to the account. We plan to use sync components of Android OS, combined with AccountManager, for future features. At the moment, we just use it to store what I have mentioned.